# Core Data Entity automatic generated class not appearing in autocomplete

Tags: swift, core-data, xcode8

Under Xcode 8.2, I have a Swift project where I created a Core Data Entity called `Paragem`. I'm trying to call `Paragem(context: mainContext)` but the method signature doesn't appear in the autocomplete. If I try to generate the class files, it complains about double declaration because Xcode automatically generates the class files in the deriveddata folder. Has anyone experienced this before? Anything I can do to remedy this?

Comment: Are you just trying to initialize it?

Comment: Are you saved changes of the model?

Comment: I'm just trying to initialize it.

Answer (score 0):

Automatically generated code is not appropriate for editing because it is regenerated whenever the model is dirtied, which is why the files live in DerivedData.

If you want to add your own functionality to automatically generated subclasses, you should create a new extension in your own source. If you want to add properties with their own storage, you can change the code generation type to "Category/Extension" and then create a class definition file in your own source tree for your new methods. [See Apple Staff Response](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/50610)

Still if you would like to generate it by your self then you can disable it in `Data Model Inspector`. see the attached screen shot for quick reference.

[image: Entity Codegen Setting]

Set **Codegen** setting to **Manual/Node** So Xcode will not stop generating automatic class definition.

I hope this helps.